# XSL XML: adding a modal popup

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
    <text>
        <title>Header1</title>
        <content>
            <p>
                <sentence>I bought <fruit>kiwi</fruit> at the grocery store.</sentence>
                <sentence>I also bought <fruit>bananas</fruit> at the store.</sentence>
            </p>
            <p>
                <sentence>She bought <fruit>kiwi</fruit> at the grocery store.</sentence>
                <sentence>She also bought <fruit>bananas</fruit> at the store.</sentence>
            </p>
        </content>
        <footer>Footer1</footer>
    </text>
    <text>
        <title>Header2</title>
        <content>
            <p>
                <sentence>He bought <fruit>pears</fruit> at the grocery store.</sentence>
                <sentence>He also bought <fruit>lemons</fruit> at the store.</sentence>
            </p>
            <p>
                <sentence>You bought <fruit>pears</fruit> at the grocery store.</sentence>
                <sentence>You also bought <fruit>lemons</fruit> at the store.</sentence>
            </p>
        </content>
        <footer>Footer2</footer>
    </text>
</file>
```

I'm trying to add a modal popup that appears when clicking on a `<sentence>` and display the entire `<content>` in the modal popup along with the header and footer. I have the following xsl that doesn't display any `<sentence>`s after adding Modal Content `<div>`s. Also, how can I pass a unique ID to Modal Content, so that it displays the correct `<content>` where the `<sentence>` belongs?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:template match="/">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="file/text/content/p"/>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fruit">
<span style="color:red;">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sentence[fruit]">
<p id="myBtn" onclick="myBtn()">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</p>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<h2>
<xsl:value-of select="file/text/title"/>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p><xsl:value-of select="file/text/content"/>
</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<h3>
<xsl:value-of select="file/text/footer"/>
</h3>
</div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the sentence, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an XPath such as

```
select="file/text/title"
```

You're saying "from the current element, select its child file, from here its child text, and from here its child title".

But file is not a child of sentence, so you're not selecting anything.

You need to select "the title element which is in the same text element as the current element". And that is

```
select="ancestor::text/title"
```

> Also, how can I pass a unique ID to Modal Content

You could leverage generate-id():

```
id="{generate-id()}"
```

or you could count how many sentences you've been through so far:

```
id="modal{count(preceding::sentence)}"
```

Comment: I'm not even getting any sentences, it's blank. Anything wrong with the modal <div>s and <script> being there within the template?

Comment: Ah sorry I hadn't noticed the file/text/p/sentence[fruit]. You forgot content there. Or it should just be //sentence[fruit]. As for the modal it should probably be with content since you want one per content, and the script should probably be unique at the end or start of the document. But no, it doesn't disturb the transformation.

Comment: thanks. I added content. Still it gives me a blank. if I move the modal and script parts to the php file, it gives me the sentences.